# How to access parent scope in Angular with typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

How can I access the scope of the parent Controller within the typescript-class?

This is my code:

```
 export class EntityOverviewCtrl extends AbstractCtrl {

    public static $inject = ["$state", "$http", "CurrentSession"];

    public EntityName: string;
    public Records: any[] = [];        

    constructor($state, $http, $parent, protected currentSession) {
        super($state, $http);

        this.init();
    }
}
```

I'm using the UI-Router and don't have a `$scope.$parent-Variable` available here...

Comment: you can inject $scope in your controller. why are you not doing it?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work..$scope is always undefined. I added the "$scope" to the inject-variable and add $scope: ng.IScope to the constructor without luck

Comment: can you post that code? I having doubt that you are doing something wrong. otherwise it should work

Comment: sorry there was an error in another class and VS didn't recreate my Javscript-Files.. I had to include the $scope in other classes which inherited the EntitiyOverviewCtrl. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "as" syntax:

```
static $inject = ["$scope"];
constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope) {
    this.$scope.$parent.vm.changedProperty = yourValue;
}
```

Comment: Indeed the vm was the case for me

Answer (score 0):

> don't have a $scope.$parent

`$parent` should point to the parent scope. The bug is elsewhere.